# Mouse position script using Chrome console ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

how can i make a script for Chrome console, to stimulate the mouse going to 2 points in a infinite loop

For example to move the mouse the point A then point B (after 100ms) , then point A again,point B and repeat .

Is this thing even possible ?

Answer (score 2):

browser-javascript is unable to control your mouse position, and that is with good reason: imagine if any website could just take control of your mouse.

however, you could just write a script in a desktop application, with a language such as python or ruby. or if u really want to use JS you could use nodejs to control the mouse, but it simply cant run in the browser